# pacemaker cluster: using resource groups to model node roles

Tags: pacemaker

I'm setting up my first pacemaker cluster, which has four nodes, and I'm trying to get it such that particular resources run on particular groups of nodes. Typically, I'm dealing with resources of which there needs to be exactly one being run somewhere within a resource group.

There are different roles within my cluster, such as:

- indexing (nodes 1 through 4)
- submission (nodes 1 and 2)
- archive (nodes 3 and 4, ideally preferring node 3)
- consumption (nodes 3 and 4, ideally preferring node 4)

The resources I have defined involve three floating IPs (these are the submission role), and two systemd services. (the floating IPs are the most important part; the rest of the software stuck does its own clustering.)

I'm trying to follow https://www.unixarena.com/2015/12/rhel-7-pacemaker-cluster-resource-group-management.html/, but I'm note sure my expectations of what a resource group can do fit into reality.

Currently, pcs resource looks like the following:

```
# pcs resource
 Resource Group: submission
     reception_ip_general   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
     reception_ip_networking    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
     reception_ip_esx   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 Resource Group: archive
     archive-writer-avro    (systemd:archiver@avro):    Started node3
     archive-writer-syslog  (systemd:archiver@syslog):  Started node3
```

There are as yet no constraints of any kind set, and its just luck that the resource have landed up where they are (I have seen one of the floating IPs being on a node4, for example)

To clarify what I'm wanting to achieve:

- reception_ip_general should run on node1 xor node2
- reception_ip_networking should run on node1 xor node2
- reception_ip_esx should run on node1 xor node2
- archive-writer-avro should run on node3 xor node4
- archive-writer-syslog should run on node3 xor node4

What I'm thinking I need is something that:

- allows me to define a group 'submission' of nodes
- allows me to put resources into the 'submission' group
- specify a location constraint such that node1 and node2 should be the ones that host things in the 'submission' group.

Or perhaps I should be looking to:

- define node attributes such each node has attributes set such that node1 might have an attribute submission_role=1, index_role=1
- specify location constraints such that resource stick to nodes with their matching attribute.

I'm sure this must be fairly simple, but so far none of the documentation I've encountered seems to model this, and I'm almost convinced that resource groups are leading me down the garden path.

Thanks for your help,
Cameron

## Updates

### pcs node attribute

I've been playing with node attributes, and have so far got the following:

```
# pcs node attribute
Node Attributes:
 node1: indexing_role=1 submission_role=1
 node2: indexing_role=1 submission_role=1
 node3: archive_role=1 consumption_role=1 indexing_role=1
 node4: archive_role=1 consumption_role=1 indexing_role=1
```

And the constraints look like these:

```
# pcs constraint location reception_ip_general rule score-attribute=submission_role defined submission_role
```

Output:

```
# pcs constraint
Location Constraints:
  Resource: archive-writer-avro
    Constraint: location-archive-writer-avro
      Rule: score-attribute=archive_role
        Expression: defined archive_role
  Resource: archive-writer-syslog
    Constraint: location-archive-writer-syslog
      Rule: score-attribute=archive_role
        Expression: defined archive_role
  Resource: reception_ip_esx
    Constraint: location-reception_ip_esx
      Rule: score-attribute=submission_role
        Expression: defined submission_role
  Resource: reception_ip_general
    Constraint: location-reception_ip_general
      Rule: score-attribute=submission_role
        Expression: defined submission_role
  Resource: reception_ip_networking
    Constraint: location-reception_ip_networking
      Rule: score-attribute=submission_role
        Expression: defined submission_role
Ordering Constraints:
Colocation Constraints:
Ticket Constraints:
```

### Node attributes for the win!

Adjusting the node attributes so I can model the preferences between node3/4 roles

```
# pcs node attribute 
Node Attributes:
 node1: indexing_role=1 submission_role=1
 node2: indexing_role=1 submission_role=1
 node3: archive_role=2 consumption_role=1 indexing_role=1
 node4: archive_role=1 consumption_role=2 indexing_role=1


# pcs status
Cluster name: mycluster
Stack: unknown
Current DC: node1 (version unknown) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Aug 15 12:19:45 2018
Last change: Wed Aug 15 12:18:20 2018 by root via crm_attribute on node1

4 nodes configured
5 resources configured

Online: [ node1 node2 node3 node4 ]

Full list of resources:

 reception_ip_general   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 reception_ip_networking    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node2
 reception_ip_esx   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 archive-writer-avro    (systemd:archiver@avro):    Started node3
 archive-writer-syslog  (systemd:archiver@syslog):  Started node3

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Put node3 into standby, and it move to node4

```
# pcs node standby node3

# pcs resource
 reception_ip_general   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 reception_ip_networking    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node2
 reception_ip_esx   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 archive-writer-avro    (systemd:archiver@avro):    Started node4
 archive-writer-syslog  (systemd:archiver@syslog):  Started node4
```

Take node3 out of standby, and it moves back to node3

```
# pcs resource
 reception_ip_general   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 reception_ip_networking    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node2
 reception_ip_esx   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
 archive-writer-avro    (systemd:archiver@avro):    Started node3
 archive-writer-syslog  (systemd:archiver@syslog):  Started node3
```

Awesome, let's try the submission tier, which has an equal score. When we 'pcs standby node1', I see things move to node2. When I 'pcs unstandby node1', it stays on node2, and when I 'pcs standby node2', things move over to node1.

If I standby node1 AND node2, then things move to node3 and node4, and then move back to node1/2 when I unstandby them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this out myself.

The way to do this is using node attributes:

1. Create a node attribute per role in your cluster. Commands such as:

   `pcs node attribute node1 submission_role=1 index_role=1`
2. The value of the attribute will be used for the score. Commands such as:

   `pcs node attribute node3 archive_role=2 consumption_role=1 index_role=1`

   `pcs node attribute node4 archive_role=1 consumption_role=2 index_role=1`
3. Create a location constraint that applies to hosts that have the attribute defined, and uses the value of that attribute for the score. Commands such as:

   `pcs constraint location archive-writer-avro rule score-attribute=archive_role defined archive_role`
4. Test using commands such as `pcs node standby node1`, `pcs node unstandby node1` and `watch pcs resource`
5. Adjust node attributes to vary the weighting (you should be able to use negative values to represent avoidance rather than preferment).

Note that the values that I've used are probably not the best; maybe 100 would be better than 1.

Thanks anyway for people pondering my question.

Cheers,
Cameron

Comment: You could "accept" your own answer.